# SessionStorage in Angular: Access and Alter the Storage from everywhere in the App (Cache Factory, ngStorage)

Tags: angularjs

I need a solution to alter and access the values in a session based store in angular.

I need to access it in code parts like this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $window, $alert, AuthService) {

    $rootScope.$on(
```

and in my controllers, and in my html, everywhere. I did not find a solution for this. I tried services (with ngStorage)

```
appServices.factory('AuthService', function ($rootScope, $localStorage){
    return {
        set: function(entidy, value) {
            $storage = $localStorage;
            $storage[entidy] = value;
        }

        get: function(entidy) {
            if (typeof $rootScope.$storage != 'undefined') {
                return $rootScope.$storage[entidy];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Writing to my service like this:

```
AuthService.set(email, 'test@test.de');
AuthService.set(token, '12345');
AuthService.set(auth, true);
```

But Getter / Setter sucks, This is not the 1990s. Also above does not work. Any ideas? Do I need a service at all to cache data in sessionStorage? Keep in mind I need to access this on the root scope (and everywhere else).

Hence `$scope.$storage = $localStorage` will fail.

Yes this question is ngStorage specific, but the same setup should be true for Angular's own cacheFactory.

**Plunkr**: http://plnkr.co/edit/GQomw4LqHCi7MJZTHZIG?p=preview

Comment: try `'email'`: `AuthService.set('email', 'test@test.de');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to assign `$localStorage` to your `$rootScope`. Whenever you need to use `$localStorage`, just inject it into your code:

```
appServices.factory('AuthService', function ($localStorage){
    return {
        set: function(entidy, value) {
            $localStorage[entidy] = value;
        },
        get: function(entidy) {
           return $localStorage[entidy];
        }
    }
});
```

In case you really need access the service though `$rootScope`, try one more step in your `.run`:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $localStorage) {
    $rootScope.storage = $localStorage;
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IeRo3fAtQa6qcJZi1Czp?p=preview

Comment: Your code works. Although I found it strange that `$rootScope.storage = $localStorage;` came after accessing the service. So I removed it - and voila we dont need rootScope at all. Strangely if I remove it from injection, the app hangs (see firebug output). So in essence this is another for that has its code reduced furthermore: http://plnkr.co/edit/PLIJPeus88FfpwuFjEFe?p=preview But why is rootScope needed at Injection time and why do we bind automatically to it?

Comment: @Sir Ben Benji: It hangs because `$rootScope.storage` will be undefined, causing exception when accessing `$rootScope.storage['email']`

Comment: @Sir Ben Benji: Actually, we don't need to assign to $rootScope as I said in my answer. I guess you only need this in case you need to data-bind with `$rootScope.storage`

Comment: Code fails also if not accessing `rootScope.storage`. Check my latest Plnkr. I guess ngStorage does some stuff we are not aware of, like binding to a scope, even if you don't explictly tell it to. Anyway, do you know what happens if I pass `$rootScope` and `$scope` into a function or controller? Can I choose then which one I want data-bind to?

Comment: @Sir Ben Benji: You should read more about dependency injection: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di . Your view binds only to `$scope`, not `$rootScope`. Assigning `storage` to `$rootScope` just to make it inherited in all `$scope` so that we don't need to assign to `$scope` everywhere.

Comment: @Sir Ben Benji: I've tried your plunk. But did not see the problem you described.

Comment: Will troubleshoot more tomorrow. Thanks for your continuing interest in this!